# Change the font size of UIPickerView from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uipicker

I am writing an `iOS` app using `Xcode`, and face a problem.

There is an `UIWebView` to load a webpage. On this webpage, there are some select elements. When user click the select, a data `picker` will automatically display for user to pick data. However, some long strings in the `picker` will be cut(e.g. a `string` "`state_city_area_block`" may display like "`state_city_ar`..."). So I think I have to make the font size of the picker smaller.

However, now I can just get the instance of the `UIPickerView`, but I don't know how to change its font size as it is generated by the `UIWebView` and I can not set the `delegate` functions for this `picker`.

Is it possible for me to change the font size of this `UIPickerView` from `UIWebView`?

---

I have tried to traverse all the UILabels in subviews of the picker, and change their font. It works when the picker appears, but when I scroll the picker, the font recovers...